# Could anybody give me an advice about how to merge a lot of small files from local to a whole file in HDFS efficiently

Tags: java, hadoop, streaming

Could anybody give me an advice about how to merge a lot of small files from normal File System to a whole file in HDFS efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your files exist on Linux you can try this command

cat *.txt > merge.log |cat merge.log|hadoop fs -put - mergedFile.log

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the below techniques

1. HAR -- [Hadoop archive files](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hadoop_archives.html)
2. [Sequence Files](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile)
3. May be use a [CombineInputFileFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html), it might be a little
   tricky to implement though you can get some help from [here](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/09/22/process-small-files-on-hadoop-using-combinefileinputformat-1/)
4. Or a different storage system like HBase

This a common problem and you should be able to google up on it, this [blog here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) should also give you some pointers

Let me know if you needed help with something more specific

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]
```

-getmerge  :  Get all the files in the directories that 
        match the source file pattern and merge and sort them to only
        one file on local fs.  is kept.

example: hadoop fs -getmerge /user/hdfs/test/ /home/hdfs/Desktop/merge
where :/user/hdfs/test/ is hdfs dir where files to be merged reside and /home/hdfs/Desktop/merge5 is local destination path where merge file will be copied.

Comment: thx for your advice,but I wanna merge lots of files from local dir to HDFS where a whole file reside.  Is there any commands to support the function.

Comment: So you want to merge these small files residing on your local dir first and then use this merged file and append it into your "main file" which resides in HDFS ?

Comment: sorry for my question is not very clear,Simply speaking I want to merge small files from local to HDFS.  For example: there is a lot of small files on local dir， Now I want to merge these small files to a big file on HDFS.   but the command "hadoop fs -getmerge" you told me is about merging small files from HDFS to local.

Comment: The solution you look for involves 2 steps 1) Merging all the files on your local system 2) Moving the merged file into HDFS, IMO the solution given by @Pradyumna does just this, have you tried it ?

Comment: thank you, I just wanna know whether there is a tool or command form hadoop which can achieve the function,and I think the solution given by @Pradyumna does work.  But I want to have more efficient way to reduce IO cost，for example get content form local small files  one by one and then append it to a HDFS file,that can reduce the IO cost of merging files local. but I think Pradyumna's solution is also OK and mark it accepted.

Comment: try to run the command cat * > newMergedFile in the folder you want to merge.